# Is the union of an uncountable ascending chain of measurable sets measurable?

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

Suppose that $I$ is an uncountable totally ordered index set and $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ is an ascending chain of measurable sets in some measurable space $(X,\Sigma)$. My question is: Is the union $\bigcup_{i\in I} X_i$ measurable?

One way to solve this would be to show that for every infinite chain $(A_j)_{j\in J}$ of sets ordered by inclusion, its union $A=\bigcup_{j\in J} A_j$ can be expressed as the union of some countable sub-chain. Is this possible perhaps?

For context: I want to make a Zorn argument, where my partially ordered set is the set of $\Sigma$-measurable sets with the inclusion ordering.

Comment: Suppose that $\alpha$ is some uncountable ordinal greater than or equal to, let's say, $\omega_2$ and the $\sigma$-algebra $A$ generated by the intervals $[0,r]$, where $r$ is a countable ordinal. Note that elements of $A$ are either countable or their complement is countable. Actually, that countable set (either them or their complements) is strictly contained in the interval $[0,\omega_1]$. The union of the increasing (uncountable) set of intervals $[0,r]$ with $r<\omega_1$ is $[0,r)$, which is uncountable with uncountable complement.

Comment: I edited my answer to include an alternative argument using Zorn's lemma. Is this the Zorn argument you had in mind?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the union of a chain of measurable sets doesn't have to be measurable. I will give a counterexample.

I assume that there is a nonmeasurable set, and that all one-element sets are measurable. And of course I assume the axiom of choice, in the form of the well-ordering theorem.

Let $A$ be a nonmeasurable set, and let $\lt$ be a relation that well-orders $A$. For each $a\in A$, let $A_a=\{x\in A:x\lt a\}$.

**Case 1.** All of the sets $A_a$ $(a\in A)$ are measurable.

If $A$ had a greatest element, call it $a$, then $A=A_a\cup\{a\}$ would be the union of two measurable sets, and so $A$ would be measurable. Since $A$ is not measurable, $A$ has no greatest element, so $A=\bigcup_{a\in A}A_\alpha$ is the union of an ascending chain of measurable sets.

**Case 2.** Not all of the sets $A_a$ are measurable.

Consider the least element $b\in A$ such that $A_b$ is nonmeasurable, and apply the argument of Case 1 to the nonmeasurable set $B=A_b$.

**P.S.** Here is a simpler argument using Zorn's lemma instead of the well-ordering theorem. Let $A$ be a nonmeasurable set, and let $P$ be the set of all measurable subsets of $A$, partially ordered by inclusion. If we assume that the union of a chain of measurable sets is always measurable, then Zorn's lemma applies, and $P$ has a maximal element; that is, there is a maximal measurable subset of $A$. But that's absurd, because we can always add one more point.

Comment: You don't have to assume the existence of non-measurable set, if you give your own $\sigma$-algebra. It is enough to take an uncountable set, and take the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the singletons. The measurable sets will be the countable subsets or those with countable complement. Then, take $A$ to be an uncountable subset with uncountable complement. With a concrete example you call all the shots.

Comment: I didn't want to give my own $\sigma$-algebra; I wanted to show that "the union of a chain of measurable sets is measurable" fails in the OP's favorite measure space, e.g., Lebesgue measure on the real line.

Comment: I cannot believe I could understood @bof argumentation with Zorn's lemma. Further more, I cannot believe how much related are the sets, measure and topology theories and also the big differences between them. Thanks dude. I must clarify, that if the maximal element of P, suppose $L$, is measurable, but if we pick $X \in P$ s.t. $X \not\le L$, then $X \cup L \in P$ and $L \le X \cup L$ which is the contradiction since $L$ is maximal. The well-ordering theorem is still visible through the Zorn's lemma, because the chain we pock could be non–countable. Let me know if I'm wrong...

Answer (score 1):

The P.S in bof's answer also answers the following quite interesting question:

Given a chain of sets indexed by a an uncountable family is the intersection equal to the intersection of some countable sub-family of them?

No. Consider the all subsets of $[0,1]$ of Lebesgue measure $1$. If the answer was yes, then by maximality argument we would reach a contradiction ("we can always [subtract] one more point.)