# Is a measurable space a kind of Topological space?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

I am reading though Probability and Martingale by Williams and came up with this question. Is there a good way to put these two concepts into perspective. I do understand them separately and was wondering if measure space is just a special case of Topological space or there is something more deeper than that.

Comment: Arbitrary unions of open sets are open but Aabitrary unions of measuarble sets need not be measuarble.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy So is this simply a wrong question to ask? Is the statement 'a measurable space is a topological space' true, false or absurd?

Comment: It is obviously wrong from the definitions.

Comment: What is true is that the [Borel sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_set) in the topological space form a $\sigma$-algebra, the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing the open sets, thus making a measurable space that is related in a natural way to the topological space.

Comment: There are some **analogies** between Measurable space and Topological spaces.  If you are interested in the theme, I suggest the book "Measure and Category - A Survey of the Analogies between Topological and Measure Spaces" by John C. Oxtoby. 

https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387905082

Comment: There is a deeper connection between these two concepts, if we are willing to forger "set of elements". Then locales serve as a basis for both measure theory and point-free topology. See [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/measurable+locale) and [here.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.05284.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Measure spaces might not be topological spaces because arbitrary unions of open sets are always open,  but arbitrary
   unions of measurable sets might not be measurable.

---

2. Topological spaces are not measurable spaces because:

- the complement of a measurable set is always measurable,  but the
  complement of an open set might not be open.
- countable intersections of measurable sets are always measurable,  but countable intersections of open sets might not
  be open.

---

This said,  there is indeed a big similarity between topological spaces and measurable spaces in the sense that both are
sets equipped with a  family of subsets satisfying a list of properties.  However the similarities stop there as it does not lead to any useful ideas.

Comment: In fact, the similarities go a little further.  You may be interested in taking a look into the book "Measure and Category - A Survey of the Analogies between Topological and Measure Spaces" by John C. Oxtoby. 

https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387905082

Comment: Here one can convince oneself that arbitrary unions of measurables sets might not be measurable: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3409449/is-the-union-of-an-uncountable-ascending-chain-of-measurable-sets-measurable

Comment: @BlueTomato, That is certainly a nice post, with an equally nice answer, but one does not need to go through such great lengths just to to provide an example of a collection (although not necessarily a chain) of measurable sets with a non-measurable union: given any non-measurable set $A$, we can express it as the union of all its singletons $\{a\}$, which are (usually) measurable sets.